# Pair up Bluetooth BLE device without pair from the Mobile Bluetooth Setting

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am developed one BLE project in android, In that i Connect, disconnect and write command successfully. But problem is that in some of the android device i need to pair up ble device from the Android mobile Bluetooth setting. Only after that i successfully connect and write. While some of mobile don't required this and connect automatically on click of connect button.

**Issue in Pixel and One plus 6T devices,**

- For Connect my BLe device in app, First I need to go to Setting and
  pair up perticular BLE device from the list.

  After these step, I used my BLE application  and do all operation
  successfully.

  There is any way to prevent this step? because end user don't know
  about this pair up.

**My Connection code is following :**

```
     mDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(MACID)
       
      val bondState = mDevice!!.bondState
        if (bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "device is BONDED")
            return
        } else if (bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
            Log.d(TAG, "device is BONDING")
            return
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "device is NOT BONDED")
        }

     mService!!.connect(MACID)        


    public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.
//        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback,
//                BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_LE);

        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);

        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
//        device.createBond();
        return true;
    }
```

Please any one suggest way to connect ble without asking for pair up manually from the settign?

Comment: What BLE device are you connecting to? What happens if you do not use the settings beforehand?

Comment: I used Axa ERL Lock 1, For lock and unlock.,  If I not pair up lock from the setting then i am not able to connect from the application. @M.Kotzjan

Comment: Axa ERL Lock 2 , is connect and lock unlock without pair up, while issue with only Axa ERL BLE lock 1.

Comment: Can you provide any log messages from an unsuccessful connection attempt?

Comment: Do you perform a BLE scan and connect to the address of the device found, or have you hardcoded an address you try to use in `connectGatt`, without first performing a scan?

Comment: I am not scanning , I got list of devices from the server and clicking on that i get mac address and i try to connect them, device is very close/near to me